# How display cyrillic in name ActiveForm Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

How display cyrillic in name ActiveForm Yii2?

If i weite "Имя", i get error in Model.

Need write name field ActiveForm - "**Имя**" but not "**name**".

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?> 

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?> //NEED <?= $form->field($model, 'Имя') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

---

```
class EntryForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email'], 'required'],
            ['name',  'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-z]\w*$/i'],
            ['name',  'string', 'length' => [3, 15]],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email',  'string', 'length' => [4, 15]],
        ]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get an error when you use Имя?

Comment: Yes. I get error in model : class EntryForm extends Model
` {
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email'], 'required'],
            ['name',  'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-z]\w*$/i'],
            ['name',  'string', 'length' => [3, 15]],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email',  'string', 'length' => [4, 15]],
        ]; 
    }
} `

Comment: please edit your post with your code...

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: error - with message 'Attribute name must contain word characters only.'

Comment: If i writed "Name", good working. If i writed "Имя",  i get error - with message 'Attribute name must contain word characters only.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Yii? There is an old bug that has this problem.   https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4408

Comment: They posted a fix in this commit: https://github.com/kmindi/yii2/commit/3242f3d2f34c4fc5681e215b8c4d858f7cbb8aa5 -- compare that same Yii file with the one you have.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Yii? -I use version 2.0.5

Comment: well, it looks like they did fix the issue but in the latest version they don't have the fix.

Answer (score 2):

`'name'` here:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>
```

represents english name of model attribute and should not be changed. Changing it to other language means you also need to change database table column accordingly, and this is considered BAD PRACTICE. Think about other developers (especially international that might support your code in future).

Less bad variation can be: `imya` but this is also BAD PRACTICE. Do not use that.

If you wan't to customize displayed label, add translation in `attributeLabels()`:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'Имя', // or Yii:t(...) in case of multilanguage site
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Good worked!

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->label('Ваше имя'); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use it as alternative when form label is special. Forgot to mention it. Defining label in `attributeLabels` most of the times is enough, especially for backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Yii...

I don't know how to easily post the diff but this will have suffice.  Modify your BaseHtml.php to have all the lines highlighted in green.

https://github.com/kmindi/yii2/commit/3242f3d2f34c4fc5681e215b8c4d858f7cbb8aa5

The bug report is here:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4408